# Can postmaster send post dated emails through a hook?

Tags: postmaster

I'm aiming to send a post dated email through postmaster. I'm (successfully)  sending out emails though a custom addon, by triggering a hook inside the custom addon and passing some data through the hook.

However, I'm trying to send out a post dated email in the same fashion and I'm not sure if it's the 'correct' way to do it.

Basically, I've set up a hook in postmaster, this is being triggered and it's also queuing the email in the **exp_postmaster_queue** table. In this table it's storing the **to_name**, the **to_email** and even a fully parsed message.

Now, when I trigger the ping url it removes the email from the queue and chucks it into the the mailbox - however the message fails to send as it's trying to send to the non parsed email variable (and the message also contains non-parsed variables) - **{hook:participant_email}**.

Does anyone know if sending a post dated email is possible through a hook, and if so how can I parse variables through?

The data seems like it's all in the queue table, so it must be reparsing (I started to pick the addon apart at which point I got a touch stuck).

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug occuring in the Postmaster addon when sending emails from the queue. The `send_from_queue` method is trying to reparse the hook template which is not working as there are no stored variables (email, to and variables in the template) in the row in `exp_postmaster_queue`. Instead, I believe it should be using the rendered message present in the column `message`.

I made and edit to the method `send_from_queue` method in the `Postmaster_lib class` - **libraries/Postmaster_lib.php** around **line 456**. Basically, I'm using the queue row data and passing that directly to the send method in the same class:

```
$parsed_object = $row;
```

I had to pass the hook settings through:

```
$parcel->settings = json_decode($parcel->settings);
```

And also a required property:

```
$row->post_date_specific = false;
```

And finally, copy the message over to the html_message property (for some reason the html and plain messages were not present in row):

```
$row->html_message = $row->message;
```

This is a bit hacky I know - I would open a pull request but a) I'm not sure if this actual cause of the issue, and b) I don't think the dev is supporting anymore.

Full code method here:

```
public function send_from_queue($row)
{

  if(!empty($row->parcel_id))
  {
    $parcel = $this->model->get_parcel($row->parcel_id);
    $parcel->entry = $this->model->get_entry($row->entry_id);

    $parcel->settings = json_decode($parcel->settings);
    $parsed_object = $this->parse($parcel);
  }

  if(!empty($row->hook_id))
  {
    $parcel = $this->model->get_hook($row->hook_id)->row();

    $parcel->settings = json_decode($parcel->settings);

    $row->post_date_specific = false;
    $row->html_message = $row->message;

    $parsed_object = $row;
  }

  $this->model->remove_from_queue($row->id);
  $this->send($parsed_object, $parcel, TRUE);

}
```

Hope this helps someone (most likely me)...